# Executing SQL Scripts to on-prem server from Azure Devops' Release Pipepline

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a console app, that does SQL script updates to an on-prem server.
This works when I run the app manually from a machine e.g. it updates the db's tables, sp's and whatever script (from a sql file) I need it to do.

Now, I am trying to use Azure DevOps' Release pipeline to be able to leverage it's CI/CD feature. But I am having issues getting the app to connect to the on-prem server, throwing this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
>
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Has anyone come across with this issue? How was it resolved?

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I think you should be good with Azure virtual network: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/connect-an-on-premises-network-to-a-microsoft-azure-virtual-network?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: I am hoping to avoid having to so any setup in Azure. But thanks, will explore this.

Comment: You should use a self-hosted agent for this deployment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install. You can install the agent of the machine you used, use this agent for the release pipeline.

Comment: thanks @sylvainmtz our devops' been setup with a self host agent already that's also used on other on-prem solution. But I am getting this error now:

>The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' was not found.

This indicates that it didn't get execute the app. I believe the previous error had the app executing but could not get connected to the on-prem sql.